# An Access Problem:Access Report color problem

Tags: ms-access

I have created a Access Report ,after that i export it to excel format.But while exporting it to the excel it lost his color and it shows like deemed. what i do?

Answer (score 0):

When you export a report to Excel or Word, isn't possible garantee that you will retain all formating specs. Why do you want a report in Excel (specially with all formats)? Is inferred that if you have a report, this should be the final output. If you want some post-processing tasks after you generate a report, you should do this directly in report or exporting just the records to Excel and then formating (for example through a macro).